# Virtualenv virtualenvwrapper and _imaging

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, imaging, virtualenvwrapper

So my Mac is correctly set up with _imaging but as soon as I create a new virtualenv with mkvirtualenv myproject and run the python interpreter

```
import _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
```

I get the following.

is there a quick fix to add my Imaging library to the virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install it from source, see this google [article](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL.html#mac).  Do NOT use Mac Ports as that way lies madness.

Answer (score 1):

Do not believe the previous comment, Macports Python + PIL works just fine :)

Based on error message you are probably somehow mixing OSX own Python and libraries with Macports ones (wrong versions).

- Install virtualenv using Macports Python, not OSX Python (command line switch to force the interpreter)
- Install native dependency libs to Macports (where is the list... I have had it)
- easy_install PIL - this should compile PIL and print status report (JPEG: OK, PNG: OK, etc.) after compilation

... OR you can symlink PIL to your virtualenv ...:

http://blog.mfabrik.com/2009/11/19/installing-python-imaging-library-pil-under-virtualenv-or-buildout/

Answer (score 1):

I have been happiest when I specified the python version and made sure that the virtualenv was self-sufficient -- no site-packages used.

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages --python=python2.6'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So there was a bit of an issue since I upgraded from 10.6 to 10.7 and it took me a few days to sort this out.

I have now subsequently re-compiled my python as 64 bit, MySQL as 64 bit and have a fully functional PIL, _imaging working even with virtualenv.

removed all my previous installations of XCode.

downloaded the 64 bit version of Python2.7.2 and installed

recompiled libjpeg in 64-bit

first of all the latest version of libjpeg, mine was version 8c

```
sudo make clean
sudo CC="-arch x86_64" ./configure --enabled-static --enable-shared
make
sudo make install
```

and then get Imaging-1.1.6

untar and cd into

```
vi setup.py
JPEG_ROOT="/usr/local/lib"
sudo python setup.py install
```

and test

then you should be able to make your virtualenv with mkvirtualenv testenv and do `sudo pip install http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz`